# NSNotificationCenter Notification Not Being Received When Posted in a Closure

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

What I am trying to accomplish is posting a notification through `NSNotificationCenter`'s default center. This is being done within a closure block after making a network call using `Alamofire`. The problem I am having is that a class that should be responding to a posted notification isn't receiving such notification.

My `ViewController` simply creates a `First` object that get's things moving:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let first = First()
    }
}
```

My `First` class creates and instance of a `Second` class and adds itself as an observer to my `NSNotificationCenter`. This is the class that can't seem to get the notification when the notification is posted.

```
class First : NSObject {
    let second = Second()
    override init(){
        super.init()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(First.gotDownloadNotification(_:)), name: "test", object: nil)
        second.sendRequest()
    }

    // NOT REACHING THIS CODE
    func gotDownloadNotification(notification: NSNotification){
        print("Successfully received download notification from Second")
    }

}
```

My `Second` class is what makes the network call through my `NetworkService` class and posts a notification in a closure once the request is successful and complete.

```
class Second : NSObject {

    func sendRequest(){
        let networkService = NetworkService()
        networkService.downloadFile() { statusCode in
            if let statusCode = statusCode {
                print("Successfully got a status code")
                // Post notification
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("test", object: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my `NetworkService` class is what makes a network call using `Alamofire` and returns the status code from the response through a closure.

```
class NetworkService : NSObject {

    func downloadFile(completionHandler: (Int?) -> ()){
        Alamofire.download(.GET, "https://www.google.com") { temporaryURL, response in
            let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
            let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

            return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
        }
            .response { (request, response, _, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("File download failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completionHandler(nil)
                } else if let response = response{
                    print("File downloaded successfully")
                    // Pass status code through completionHandler to Second
                    completionHandler(response.statusCode)
                }
        }

    }
}
```

The output after execution is:

> File downloaded successfully
>   Successfully got a status code

From this output I know the download was successful and `Second` got the status code from the closure and posted a notification right after.

I believe that I have tried resolving most other suggestions on Stack Overflow related to not receiving notifications such as objects not being instantiated before notification is posted or syntax of either adding an observer or posting a notification.

Does anyone have any idea why the posted notification is not being received in the `First` class?

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried changing `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("test", object: nil)` to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("test", object: nil)
                }` however that didn't seem to work. Is this correctly running on the main queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is a direct relationship between `First` and `Second` the protocol/delegate pattern is the better way to notify. Even better with this pattern and you don't have to take care of unregistering the observer. `NSNotificationCenter` is supposed to be used only if there is no relationship between sender and receiver.

And basically the thread doesn't matter either.

```
protocol SecondDelegate {
  func gotDownloadNotification()
}

class Second : NSObject {

  var delegate : SecondDelegate?

  init(delegate : SecondDelegate?) {
    self.delegate = delegate
  }

  func sendRequest(){
    let networkService = NetworkService()
    networkService.downloadFile() { statusCode in
      if let statusCode = statusCode {
        print("Successfully got a status code")
        // Post notification
       self.delegate?.gotDownloadNotification()
      }
    }
  }
}

class First : NSObject, SecondDelegate {
  let second : Second

  override init(){
    super.init()
    second = Second(delegate:self)
    second.sendRequest()
  }

  func gotDownloadNotification(){
    print("Successfully received download notification from Second")
  }
}
```

Comment: This works beautifully! I was not aware that `NSNotificationCenter` was only to be used when the classes were disjoint. Thank you for the clarification and answer.

Comment: It's more a recommendation than a direction.